# Highcharts legend events style edit

Tags: highcharts

this is my process:
[image]

and my question is that how to edit the legend to two rows and three in each row. I try to edit itemDistance, but on a different computer, the legend's style also has edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the width of the legend and the width of each legend item.  It will ... items that are wider than the itemWidth.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.width https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemWidth

```
legend: {
    width: 450,
    itemWidth: 150,

},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcxL75hh/